# Isabelle - Nitpick counterexample usage

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I would like to complete this proof.

How can I easily/elegantly use the values found by `nitpick`?   (What to write at the `...` part?)

Alternatively, how can I use the fact that `nitpick` found a counterexample to finish the proof?

```
lemma Nitpick_test: "¬(((a+b) = 5) ∧ ((a-b) = (1::int)))" (is "?P")
  proof (rule ccontr)
    assume "¬ ?P"
    nitpick
    (* Nitpicking formula... 
       Nitpick found a counterexample:

       Free variables:
         a = 3
         b = 2
     *)      
  show "False" by ...      
qed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem does not hold as stated, because if `a = 3` and `b = 2`, the statement evaluates to `False`. For other values of `a` and `b`, however, the statement does hold. Thus, as `a` and `b` are implicitly universally quantified, you cannot prove the theorem as stated.

If you want to instead prove

```
theorem "EX a b. a + b = 5 & a - b = (1 :: int)"
```

you can use `rule exI[where x="..."]` to provide the witness `...` for the existential quantifier, so `3` and `2` in this case.